# There is an error when importing the Room library

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

**Errors only occur when importing room libraries.**

There was no problem when importing kapt and ksp, but An error occurs only when you add a room library

"https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room?hl=ko." I followed what was said here

Below is my build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'    // 추가
    id 'com.google.devtools.ksp' version "1.5.31-1.0.0"
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.roomtest2"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    //ROOM LIBRARY
    def roomVersion = "2.4.2"

    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion")
    annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")

    // To use Kotlin annotation processing tool (kapt)
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")
    // To use Kotlin Symbolic Processing (KSP)
    ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")

    // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion")

    // optional - RxJava2 support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$roomVersion")

    // optional - RxJava3 support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-rxjava3:$roomVersion")

    // optional - Guava support for Room, including Optional and ListenableFuture
    implementation("androidx.room:room-guava:$roomVersion")

    // optional - Test helpers
    testImplementation("androidx.room:room-testing:$roomVersion")

    // optional - Paging 3 Integration
    implementation("androidx.room:room-paging:2.5.0-alpha02")
}
```

Error message:

```
Unable to find method ''void org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.<init>(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinJvmOptions)''
'void org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.<init>(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinJvmOptions)'

Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.

Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

**Hi**, Do the following

- **Remove extra dependencies**, because they are suitable for specific uses. such as the following

```
annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")
implementation("androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$roomVersion")
implementation("androidx.room:room-rxjava3:$roomVersion")
implementation("androidx.room:room-guava:$roomVersion")
testImplementation("androidx.room:room-testing:$roomVersion")
implementation("androidx.room:room-paging:2.5.0-alpha02")
```

Also, you will not need the following items for normal use

```
id 'com.google.devtools.ksp' version "1.5.31-1.0.0"
ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")
```

2- Select the **Invalidate Caches** option from the **File** menu and checked the **Clear file system cache and Local History** option in the opened dialog and then click the **Invalidate and restart** option.

3- After restarting Android Studio, select **Sync project with Gradle Files** from the **File** menu and wait for the above operation to be completed.